# downgrade MariaDB 10.4 to MariaDB 10.1 on centos7

Tags: centos7, cwp

downgrade MariaDB 10.4 to MariaDB 10.1 on centos7

i have this error msg

Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/garbd from install of galera-25.3.26-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package galera-4-26.4.2-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64
Error Summary

so how to uninstall galera-25.3.26-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64

my system centos7

1- i create file /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

2-
    service mysql stop 
    yum remove MariaDB-server MariaDB-client

3-
    yum clean all
    yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client net-snmp perl-DBD-MySQL -y
    yum update -y

Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/garbd from install of galera-25.3.26-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package galera-4-26.4.2-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64

Error Summary

so how to uninstall galera-25.3.26-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64

my system centos7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your terminal while running with a privileged user like root,I uninstalled galera with

```
yum remove galera*
```

If your MariaDB install needs galera it will install the galera version required by your MariaDB installation.

That's how I did it on my CentOS 7.